# Is JPA PersistenceContextType managed by container?

Tags: jpa

JPA defines PersistenceContextType, but it is not referenced anywhere in JPA api.

```
public enum PersistenceContextType {
    TRANSACTION,
    EXTENDED
}
```

Is persistence context (whether transaction or extended) is managed by container(e.g. JEE), not JPA itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it is not referenced anywhere in JPA api

It is referenced by the declarative API - the `type` property of the `@PersistenceContext` annotation. It wouldn't make sense for it to be referenced by any programmatic API, because application-managed `EntityManagers` are *always* of the `EXTENDED` type, as the `TRANSACTION` type wouldn't make much sense.

> Is persistence context (whether transaction or extended) is managed by container(e.g. JEE), not JPA itself?

Not entirely sure I understand the question but, as per [the spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) (Section 7.6):

> When a container-managed entity manager is used, the lifecycle of the persistence context is always
>   managed automatically, transparently to the application, and the persistence context is propagated with
>   the JTA transaction.

Note that a container-managed, `EXTENDED` persistence context can only be requested (using `@PersistenceContext(type = EXTENDED)`) in stateful beans, which are barely used nowadays.

(see that section, and the sections that follow, for more details on how transaction and extended scopes work)

EDIT:

As for *why* `@PersistenceContext` and `PersistenceContextType` is part of the JPA **API**, the answer is: why shouldn't it? The JPA **API** is primarily a JEE API and everything persistence-related that your app may want to use as an API goes in there. In JEE context, Hibernate, EclipseLink etc. are *technically* **not** implementations of the JPA API; rather, they're [service providers for the `PersistenceProvider` service](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider). It's a very subtle difference; however, even though they obviously do 99% percent of the work, from the application's point of view, it is still the *container* that *provides (exposes)* the JPA API.

(Another point of view could be that JPA providers implement the *programmatic* part of the API while containers implement the *declarative part*, but that's a purely academic discussion).

Comment: JPA has no such API for a container to call to set PersistenceContext type (extended or transaction), like entityManager.setPersistenceContextType(...). So I guess it must be handled by container. right?

Comment: Yup. As I said, when you inject an `EntityManager` using `@PersistenceContext(type = EXTENDED)` in a stateful bean, the container will provide you with an extended `EntityManager`. Otherwise, you'll get the default transaction-scoped `EntityManager`. On the other hand, if you obtain the `EntityManager` via `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`, the result will always be an extended `EntityManager`

Comment: Can container ask JPA provider to create an transaction-scoped EntityManager? If yes, but there is no such JPA api. If no, container must destroy persistence context once a transaction is completed, and create a new one for a new transaction. If that is the case, the container(not JPA provider) is managing the persistence context.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, why the type PersistenceContextType is defined in JPA since JPA provider will not give you different types of EntityManagers.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, the container is managing the persistence context, or rather, it is creating/destroying `EntityManager`s, telling them to synchronize with JTA etc. as required (that's what is meant by a 'container-manager entity manager', after all). You can see [how it's done for Glassfish](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/562677552f8b9325435101d9eda12a8ee3a8f457/appserver/common/container-common/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/container/common/impl/EntityManagerWrapper.java), for example

Comment: I put the answer to the other part of your question in my updated answer, since it wouldn't fit in a comment